Library to display paths inside a shopping centre
I need a library to create paths inside shopping centers that allows even several floors. In principle I had seen MapboxGL but being in principle only for a centre I do not know if it is worth it or better to look for something simpler, besides MapBoxGL I see something complex from my current knowledge, I have worked with Leaflet and d3 but so far little more related to maps. I've done a search on the internet but I don't see any other options. What I need is to create a web page that allows to navigate inside a shopping centre, to be able to filter the shops by type and to show custom paths to get from one shop to another or at least to show them from some predefined data. Here is an example:

It should be a library that allows you to navigate by moving the cursor, change floor plan if possible, mark the paths that are previously defined... Starting from OpenStreetsMaps, any suggestion is welcome, thanks.
